# lighttpd, fastcgi and application script written in "C" using libfcgi - Weird system error message

Tags: c, linux

I get a wierd Linux system message "Transport Endpoint is not connected" in response to a write call  immediately after a successful open call. All this happens immediately after a Slackware Linux 2.6.33.4 reboot.

I'm writing a forms-handler in C and it runs under lighttpd and fastcgi (and before some smart alec pipes up and asks 'why am I not using his/her favourite language, it's because I like C --- OK? OK!).

I've got the major facilities of the application running - it displays index.htm (which is a form) and when the form is 'Submit'ted, finds the program I've written which correctly processes the contents returned and displays the next form.  It's got complex enough that now I need to print some debugging statements somewhere, to give me some feedback from program additions. Thus arises the problem.

Research indicates that this message usually means that the endpoint of the file path is not or has become not mounted but /tmp/debug.log (which is the file I'm trying to create/append-to lives on the root partition. But then why is the open() successful but the write() is not?

The program fragment below is the bit which is giving trouble. The printf() statements send output to the web interface (for those unfamiliar with libfcgi) to give me some idea what's happening.

I can't get my (properly indented) code through this forum's demented code filter and I can't attach it in a zip file, so you'll just have to take my word that the syntax is correct.

Any clues?

Comment: To have your code appear as code inside your question, extra indent each line by four spaces.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the `ENOTCONN` from a call to `write()`? Dare showing just those few lines from the call to `write()` to logging the error?

Comment: If you're unable to format your source using alk's instructions, at least post your code on pastebin and link to it so someone can help you format it into your question.

Comment: alk. Thank you but I tried that, plus selecting the code's text and hitting ctrl-K as advised - no joy.  I think the problem arises because some of my lines of code are too long to fit in the provided window.

Comment: alk. Yes, I'm pretty sure that's the condition. 
xorspark I'll put the code up on my web server and post a link. Unreasonable of me to expect useful comments if the code's not visible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about pastebin xorspark - new to me. I believe the URL is  [link](http://pastebin.com/w8Qmkf2w) . It looks a bit scrappy at the mo with some code I tried commented out and printf() statements added in to send some output to the web client. Enjoy.
Peter.

Comment: This is the first few lines of the text output to the web client by the code referred in the above link.  The lighttpd executable, the script which starts it and the entire tree of /home/lighttpd belongs to user lighttpd:lighttpd  who is the user who executes the starting script.

DEBUG: Message is: "Content-type: text/html "
 Cannot write to log file "/tmp/debug.log"
 System error message is: "Transport endpoint is not connected"
 DEBUG: Message is: " argName[0] = "operation", arg[0] = "choose.htm" "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if(fd = open(DEBUG_FILE_NAME, (O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR), (S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IRUSR)) < 0)
```

results in `fd` being set to the result of `open(DEBUG_FILE_NAME, (O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR), (S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IRUSR)) < 0` which most likely is `0`.

So the `write(fd, ...` tries to ***write*** to `stdin`, which is weird, so you get a weird error ... ;-)

To fix this fix the parenthesis.

You could do this for example in save manner by using Yoda-Conditions:

```
if (0 > (fd = open(DEBUG_FILE_NAME, (O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR), (S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IRUSR))))
```

("save" in terms that everything important is at the left in *one* place: `if (0 > (fd = open(...`)

Comment: Considerations of writing style aside......
A few additions to debugging statements showed that you are absolutely right, fd is set to 0.
This leads to the question 'How do I do file I/O within my forms handler' which is required to manipulate files as it's main purpose.

Comment: As for the above question I had, indeed, left out a pair of parentheses - a beginner's error.